# How to display Listbox items in tabular form in c#

Tags: c#

I have now been searching around how to make a table in listbox in C#

What I have been succeeding so far is using this method

```
String str = "{1, -30}{2, -30}";
```

The issue with this is that it only do spaces and the text do not really align.

I would like to have it look like this:

```
Test:                       some text
Sometexthere:     text
```

I am using c# windows forms

Thanks!

Comment: its because listbox doesn't support Column view i guess. thats why Datagrid exists. you can only add "Items" to the listbox which will be rows only.

Comment: Use Listview or DataGrid

Comment: I have it only like this which will create sort of column. 

String str = "{0, -20}{1, -20}";
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(str,"test:", "some text"));
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(str, "sometexthere:", "text"));

Yes I know that ListBox shouldnt be used as table but it is an requirment in this assignment.

Comment: Why not use ListView instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [`ListBox.MultiColumn Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2)
2. or you will need to set the font to a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) Then you can use, [`String.PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.7.2)/[`String.PadRight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.7.2) to build up that columns
3. Alternatively, you can choose a control that natively supports this, like a [`ListView`](http://ListView) or [`DataGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagrid-control-overview-windows-forms)